# Security trimming for OneDrive in the Sharepoint Online search not completely working?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, onedrive-for-business, security-trimming

When searching with people's names in the Sharepoint Online search at the Everything level, search will bring up people's OneDrive pages:

[image]

However, I don't have access to that first search result:

[image]

Shouldn't the security trimming prevent that from showing up at all in search?

If this is expected behavior, is there any way to hide search results from other people's OneDrive pages?